# NSString Issue manipulation Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSString *string1;
string1=@"aa bb cc dd";
[string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"------string1 is %@--------", string1);
```

I expect `aabbccdd` but its still `aa bb cc dd`. the space didn't got taken out.

Comment: 92 questions, but you still don't know how to format code?

Comment: lol, what a niggerty mindset, throwing that minus behind the back all of a sudden.  folk like that usually can't do big thing in life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString is not mutable, so `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` is returning a new NSString, that you'll have to assign to a variable.

```
NSString *string1 = @"aa bb cc dd";
string1 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, so this may not be the best answer, but this works for me.

```
NSMutableString *mutableString; 
mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"aa bb cc dd"];

NSRange range;
range = NSMakeRange(0, [mutableString length]);
[mutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:range];
```